# Swap two files in bash

Tags: bash, files, rename

How do I swap two files in Linux console with minimum typing?

Boring approach:

```
$ mv file1.dat fileX.dat
$ mv file2.dat file1.dat
$ mv fileX.dat file2.dat
```

Comment: Using script: `T=$(mktemp tmp.XXXXXXXX); mv -- "$1" "$T" && mv -- "$2" "$1" && mv -- "$T" "$2"`

Comment: If your `mv` supports `-b` you could golf it shorter like this: `mv -b file1.dat file2.dat && mv file2.dat~ file1.dat`.